# Unwanted row breaks in references bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, doi, gap

[Full Minimal Example Zip File](https://cloudstore.uni-ulm.de/s/edRoXTETkftxSpk)

it's the first time I'm working with LaTex and I have some issues with the **bibliography**. For some **references** but not for all, the **doi is strangely presented in a new row with a gap**. How can I change that? **I used a Springer template from here: https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support**

Here are relevant information:

```
\documentclass[sn-apa]{sn-jnl}% APA Reference Style
\bibliography{sn-bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{sn-apacite}%
```

And here is a **picture of the problem**:
[image]

And here are the entries in my .bib file:

```
@article{Cousineau2010, 
title={Outliers detection and treatment: a review.}, 
volume={3}, 
url={https://revistas.usb.edu.co/index.php/IJPR/article/view/844}, 
doi = {10.21500/20112084.844}, 
number={1}, 
journal={International Journal of Psychological Research}, 
author={Cousineau, Denis and Chartier, Sylvain}, 
year={2010}, 
pages={58–-67} 
}
@book{Cramer2008,
author = {Cramer, Henriette and Evers, Vanessa and Ramlal, Satyan and {Van Someren}, Maarten and Rutledge, Lloyd and Stash, Natalia and Aroyo, Lora and Wielinga, Bob},
booktitle = {User Modeling and User-Adapted Interaction},
doi = {10.1007/s11257-008-9051-3},
number = {5},
pages = {455--496},
title = {{The effects of transparency on trust in and acceptance of a content-based art recommender}},
volume = {18},
year = {2008},
}
```

The Cramer reference is of type book.I want no gap between the doi of Cousineau and the rest of the references. **If I change the Cousineau reference in my .bib file from article to proceeding, the doi shows correctly. How can I change the settings of article references?**

Here is potentially relevant code from the sn-jnl file (line 1685):

```
\if@APA@refstyle%   
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}%   
\gdef\NumBib{NO}%   
\bibliographystyle{sn-apacite}%  
\def\refdoi#1{\urlstyle{rm}\url{#1}}%   
\renewcommand{\doiprefix}{}%   
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand{\BPBI}{.}% Period between initials - command from apacite.sty   }%   
\setlength{\bibsep}{1em}%  
\def\bibfont{\reset@font\fontfamily{\rmdefault}
\normalsize\selectfont}%
```

Please let me know if more information is needed to understand the issue.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example. You tex example is incomplete so we cannot just copy it and test as is.  Additionally as `sn-jnl` is not a known class (it is not in TeXLive for example), please provide a link to it. Your example also does not provide any information as to which bibtex style is used. Does adding the `xurl` package help? Your problem is clearly the formating of the URL in `Cousineau2010` and so we need to know exactly how that text is generated and that is not possible with the date you have provided so far.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments and information. The link to the Springer LaTex template I used is here: https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support. Currently, I do not load any natbib or biblatex packages in my preamble. After I read your comment, I looked into the sn-jnl file. I found some code starting in line 1685 - I will update my original question.

Comment: I also figured out that if I change in my .bib file an article to a proceeding type, then the doi shows correctly. So I assume that somehow the specification of the setting for article references is not correct.

Comment: using the "xurl" package doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Additionally if you want help then please provide a full minimal example, not these sniplets. Note that if `apacite` is in use (it is not in your sniplet but might in the class, I haven't looked, then `apacite` changes the URL package (if loaded) at the start of the document. If neither your document or the class actually loads the `url` package, then you can get around this using `\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{xurl}}` as it then (might) come later than the `apacite` changes. Problem is that `apacite` has not been updated since 2013 long before `xurl` arrived.

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{xurl}}` did not work unfortunately. I haven't figured out yet how to better provide a full minimal example.

Comment: (1) get rid of packages that are not related to your bibliography, add the two citations, add `\bibliographystyle` (if not set by the class) and `\bibliography`

Comment: You need to make a document that others can copy and test as is. That is it needs to contain relevant document class, relevant preamble, `\begin{document}`, relevant document body for the question and `\end{document}`. You are not providing any, sorry cannot help much.

Comment: I added a link to download a zip file containing all that information.

Comment: In any case, thank you very much for the comments, so I can provide better information for other users.

Comment: If you have been asked by Springer to use their template you should probably ask them for support and not try do make unofficial changes that they will probably redo in their production.

Comment: Honestly, looking more at the code, it does not seem that apacite even wraps a URL in a `\url` command at all. And thus for a bibliography with this setup, you are not allowed for example `_` in an URL. This setup is very outdated.

Comment: Yes, I really had issues with my URLs and added a ` backslash\` everytime I had an URL containing an `_`

Comment: Anyway, I now contacted their support

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

Here is a nasty idea. If we look at the generated `.bbl` file we see

```
\begin{APACrefURL}
  {https://revistas.usb.edu.co/index.php/IJPR/article/view/844}
  \end{APACrefURL}
```

with the env being defined in `apacite.sty` as

```
\newenvironment{APACrefURL}[1][]{%
  \ifx\@empty#1\@empty
    \BRetrievedFrom % Retrieved from
  \else
    \BRetrieved{#1}%  Retrieved <date>, from
  \fi
}{}
```

which basically means that the URL part is never given any special formatting. Indeed if we change the URL in the example to contain a `_` compilation fails.

But what if we could get the env to read the URL as an argument and then we control the formatting. This requires either a modern LaTeX installation or the `xparse` package.

```
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{APACrefURL}{ o m }{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
    \BRetrievedFrom %
  }{
    \BRetrieved{#1} %
  }
  \url{#2}
}{}
```

This uses `\url` which is better than nothing.

It does seem that if we also add

```
\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{xurl}}
```

then the URL formatting seems better (slightly better lines breaks, but I still don't think we get the break at any char that `xurl` might normally bring to the table)

Note that the code used is just the `sn-article.tex` template from the Springer link.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions, I'll try that out!